# In T-SQL, How to sum row values that are also calculated in Count method

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on T-SQL script where I have column that Sum value, now I need to add all the rows value and use to calculate percentage. My question is how I sum values in all rows, considering this row also did count()

```
SELECT 
    q.Id AS QuestionId,
    ansOpt.QuestionOptionId AS QuestionOptionId,
    qOpt.Value,
    COUNT(ansOpt.QuestionOptionId) AS QuestionOptionCount,
    (((CONVERT(DECIMAL, COUNT(ansOpt.QuestionOptionId)))) / 8) * 100 AS AnswerCoutPercentage
    -- COUNT(QuestionOptionCount) // need help here 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Responses] AS res 
GROUP BY 
    q.Id, ansOpt.QuestionOptionId, qOpt.Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, since I need to use the stored procedure so I did in following way

```
DECLARE @totalAnswer INT = 0;
SELECT @totalAnswer = SUM(a.TotalCount)
    FROM 
        (SELECT COUNT(ansOpt.QuestionOptionId) AS TotalCount
            FROM [dbo].[Responses] AS res 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Surveys] AS sur ON res.SurveyId = sur.Id  
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Answers] AS ans ON res.Id = ans.ResponseId
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[AnswerOptions] AS ansOpt ON ans.Id = ansOpt.AnswerId
        WHERE sur.ConsultationId = '00000001-0012-4D34-95D8-0000000000'
        AND ans.QuestionId = '0ADED4CE-5385-5826-4880-00000000000'
        GROUP BY ansOpt.QuestionOptionId) AS a
```